# Strange NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE after working before

Tags: html, image, audio, canvas

I'm having a weird problem while programming a html 5 shooter. When I turn off the sound engine, it runs well "forever", but when sound is turned on, after a while chrome and Firefox both crash. All sounds have being loaded at played hundreds of times. chrome just says "oops". Firefox shows this up in the console, right before it crashes (completely away):

```
 Image corrupt or truncated: {some png-file path} 

 NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABE: (78 times)  image.js:110

 Image corrupt or truncated: {another png-file path}  

 NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABE: (104 times)  image.js: 76
```

Well, these images have already be loaded and drawn for a thousand times (hundrets of enemies and particles per frame).

Both lines in image.js 76+110 are something like

```
myContext.drawImage(myImage, ... );
```

How can this happen, when these images have already worked hundred times before? And why does it only happen when I play audio? 
Any ideas?

Comment: I see, it's hard to help without more code. My problem is, that the project has grown and there's too much code to paste it here. What I can say already is, that the images are not reloaded every time. You can see it in action here: http://igoa-music.de/Space_Shooter/spaceshooter.html. Sound is turned off, turn it on in the menu and then play the game. But I cannot expect, that one reviews the while project. I just hoped, that someone had similar strange effects before.

Comment: I've finally solved the problem.
As I stated above, the game only crashed when audio playback was used. Even though the error message seemed to have to do with image drawing. So I've researched my sound engine and found out, that the problem must have to do with starting playback of the same sound at the same time. Within some scenes of the game many enemies fire exactly at the same time and so the fire sound was triggered multiple times. When I check, if the sound has been triggered already in the current frame and avoid playing it back twice, everything works well.